# How to determine radiation at a certain distance from a sunlamp

Tags: power, distance, radiation

I have a sunlamp, with four UV bulbs, emitting UVA and UVB. These are parallel-mounted tube bulbs and the total area of the light emitting area is 20 cm × 25 cm = 0.05 m<sup>2</sup>. Each bulb is 15 W and so this is 60 W / 0.05 m<sup>2</sup> = 1200 W/m<sup>2</sup> = 1.2 kW/m<sup>2</sup>.

I'd like to be able to calculate W/m<sup>2</sup> of radiation at different distances from the lamp, to ensure that I don't exceed the amount that I would typically get on a sunny day. I understand the 1/R<sup>2</sup> rule, which indicates that as you if you double your distance from a source, you quarter the power. However, I don't know the radiation at a distance from the source, I only know it *at source*, where my distance from it is zero. Because zero times anything is zero, doubling my distance isn't something I can do.

So, two questions:

1. How do I determine the power from the lamp at different distances?
2. How much UVA and UVB radiation typically hits the earth on a sunny day? I can only find figures for total radiation, which is about 1.35 kW/m<sup>2</sup>?

Comment: The UV radiation from the bulbs is *not* equal to the rated power consumption of the bulbs. The efficiency is way less than 100% for incandescents, and still not 100% for LEDs.  You'll need a datasheet, or search for typical efficiencies of that type of bulb.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Very good point. If I find out, how would I then determine the power dropoff as I move away from the lamp?

Comment: Your sunny day problem can get some light from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet Without knowing the radiation spectrum of the lamps, their spatial radiation pattens nor the exact geometric construction of your system no calculations are possible. The calculations you should learn are known as elementary radiometry. It's not photometry because you do not estimate visibility. But both use the same basic math.

Comment: @MarkRoworth The UV lamp vendor should provide a UV intensity at a stated distance. Then, just adjust that using the inverse square law. For example, this vendor https://www.americanairandwater.com/uv-lamps.htm gives intensity in microwatts per square centimeter @ 1 meter distance. If you're working at 2 meters, the intensity is 1/4 that level, etc.